# How to add an ActivityType or an Activity to your bot in javascript discordjs version 14?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to know how to set my activity status for my bot.

Like "Watching youtube.com"

Or "playing a game."

I've tried following the discord api document but it does not tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify your activity type or set an activity type in discordjs version 14 you can do it by simply writing.

First you need to add const

```
{ Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType, Guild } = require('discord.js');
```

And then you can set your activity type as the following:

```
client.user.setActivity('Message goes here', { type: ActivityType.Streaming});
```

There are 6 different types.

```
Playing | 0
Streaming | 1
Listening | 2
Watching | 3
Custom | 4
Competing | 5
```

For example if you would like to set your bots status to playing a game you would do it as following:

```
client.user.setActivity('game', { type: ActivityType.Playing});
```

https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what version of Discord.JS you are using?

v12:

> client.user.setActivity("you", {type: "WATCHING"});

v14:

In v14, you will need to use ActivityType, make sure to add "ActivityType" before require("discord.js"); like this

> const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');

then this is the code:

> client.user.setPresence({   activities: [{ name: `discord.js v14`,
> type: ActivityType.Watching }],   status: 'dnd', });

heres a list of the activity types:

```
ActivityType.Competing  
ActivityType.Listening  
ActivityType.Playing    
ActivityType.Streaming  
ActivityType.Watching
```

Comment: Does not work for me.